# How to update entity_type_id in table?

Tags: database, magento-2.1, magento-1.6, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I have the situation that I want to migrate a Magento 1.6.2.0 database to Magento 2.1 using the data-migration-tool. The tool is mapping some fields by the `entity_type_id`. My problem is that the `entity_type_id`s in Magento 1 are customized. My solution would be to change them to their original values, so the migration tool will work. Sometimes there are foreign key contraints in tables, sometimes not, so it's not just updating the id's in the `eav_entity_type` table.

Can anyone provide one or multiple SQL Queries that change the `entity_type_id`s (consistently) in all tables? I don't care about custom tables from extensions.